# Files not being attached to POST request (axios) while sending with Postman works

Tags: node.js, axios, postman, http-post, multer

Im trying to understand why my files are not being sent with axios request from frontend while I can send them with Postman.

I have Nodejs backend with multer to accept files like so,

```
app.use(multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).array('datafiles', 4))
```

In backend route I handle this as follows

```
export const postFarmData = async(req, res, next) => {

  console.log(req.files)

    for (const file of req.files) {
        const json = await csv().fromString(file.buffer.toString('utf-8'))
        for(const entry of json) {
            const validation = validateDataRow(entry)
            if(validation){
               await FarmDataModel.create(entry)
            }
        };
    }
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: "Post new farm data"})
}
```

with Postman these are headers
[image: postman headers]

and this is body
[image: request body]

in frontend I select files and make request like s0

```
const [uploadFile, setUploadFile] = useState()

const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const dataArray = new FormData();
    dataArray.append("datafiles", uploadFile);
    const response = await axios.post( API_ROOT,
        dataArray, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
    })
    const result = await response
    console.log(result)
}

return <div className="addfile-container">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="files">Select file(s)</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple onChange={(e) => setUploadFile(e.target.files)}/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

What happens is that sending from frontend responds ok, but req.files are empty. So no file reaches backend.

With Postman files reach server and are processed ok.
What is wrong that my files from frontend are not reaching backend?

EDIT: Adding chrome devtools Post request headers
[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to the `Network` tab in Chrome Devtools, record your `POST` and check the headers

Comment: @mmomtchev added headers and payload images to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "file" is in fact a `FileList` because you accept multiple files

You should extract them one by one:

`dataArray.append("datafiles", uploadFile);`

should be

```js
// uploadFile is an HTML input element: <input type="file" id="myfileinput" multiple>

// loop through files
for (let i = 0; i < uploadFile.length; i++) {
    const file = uploadFile.item(i);
    dataArray.append("file" + i, file);
}
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList